# `updatedb` cannot open file `mlocate.db`

Tags: filesystem, files, search, locate, updatedb

When I run `updatedb` from a terminal, I get this error:

```
updatedb: can not open a temporary file for `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db'
```

Any ideas about how to get `updatedb` to work?

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old post, but I do not see this solution elsewhere.

The problem is not the `mlocate.db` file, as you'd expect.  It is the permissions on the `mlocate` executable.  This will fix the issue:

```
sudo chmod 2755 /usr/bin/mlocate
```

This is the source of the trouble:

```
$ ls -lathr /usr/bin/mlocate 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root mlocate 39K Nov 17  2014 /usr/bin/mlocate
```

You need a `setuid` bit on the group to allow you to run the `locate` command without `sudo`.  Once it is fixed, your `ls` output should look like this:

```
$ ls -lathr /usr/bin/mlocate 
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root mlocate 39K Nov 17  2014 /usr/bin/mlocate
```

Simply doing a `chmod` as some others recommend against the `db` file itself will only work until the next time someone runs `updatedb`.  Then the permissions will be reset.

Comment: I am not sure how this would be a security risk, as that is actually how it is configured by Ubuntu out of the box.   The security risk would be never finding out what changed it to begin with.. :)

Answer (score 3):

For me after updates to Ubuntu 14 I still kept getting

```
$ locate chruby
locate: can not open `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': Permission denied
```

so the issue was not about broadening read permissions on that file, unlike other answers say.

My  "*nonrootuser*" is *master*. So as *root* I added that user to the group *mlocate*:

```
# addgroup master mlocate
```

After listing the details of that directory to see ownerships:

```
# ls -al /var/lib/mlocate
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root        4096 Jun 19 13:21 ./
drwxr-xr-x 94 root root        4096 Jan 23 11:27 ../
-rw-r-----  1 root mlocate 50134121 Jun 19 13:21 mlocate.db
```

Answer (score 2):

Please run the command with `sudo`:

```
sudo updatedb
```

Comment: Using `sudo` is unnecessary when the user is added to the `mlocate` group.

Comment: @xiota - It's a super-simple answer, though, and worked without having to add the user to a group (which is often the case, if you're working on a personal computer with no other users.)  I enter `sudo <command>` all day long, but haven't used `updatedb` in a while and forgot that it needed those permissions.  Something like, `updatedb: can not open a temporary file for '/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db'` often leads me to believe it has nothing to do with permissions and that the file is simply not there (since I don't see that often.)  This was the fastest and most efficient answer, in this case.

Comment: Something "working" doesn't mean it's a good solution.  Running programs as administrator on Windows also "worked", and look how much havoc that wreaked.

Answer (score -1):

Read `man updatedb` and learn how to write `updatedb`'s output elsewhere, in a directory you have write permission for.